# Angular 9. Synchronous *ngFor on the page

Tags: angular, typescript, async-await

So, I'm recievig a list of subjects from server, then take excersises on each subject by **subject.id** (from the server) and store all the subjects with their excersises in **subEx** variable *(classes are listed in the bottom)*

```
  subjects:Subject[] 
  temp:Excersise[] = []
  subEx:SubjectExcersise[] = []

  constructor(private exService: ExcersiseService, private subService: SubjectService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getSubjects()
  }

  getSubjects(){
    let id = localStorage.getItem("id")
    this.subService.GetSubjectsBuUserId(localStorage.getItem("id")).subscribe(
      res => {
        this.subjects = res
        for (const sub of this.subjects){
          this.exService.GetExcesisesBySubject(sub.name).subscribe(
            res=>{
              this.temp = res
              this.subEx.push(new SubjectExcersise(sub, this.temp))
              console.log(this.subEx)
            }
          )
        }
      },
    )
  }
```

Get subject and excersises via simple http.get

```
  GetExcesisesBySubject(subName:string){
    return this.http.get<any>(this._getExcesisesBySubject+"/"+subName)
  }
```

Then I display all the subjects as buttons and add excersises as dropdown to each button.

```
      <div class="list-group list-group-flush">
          <button *ngFor="let sub of subEx" type="button" class="btn btn-success dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
            {{sub.subject.name}}
            <div class="dropdown-menu">
                <a *ngFor="let ex of sub.excersises" class="dropdown-item">{{ex.title}}</a>
            </div>
          </button>
      </div>
```

The problem is that after every page reload subjects have
[different order and all subjects have the same random excersises](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VkusL.png) (on the picture all subjects have "Task 1", "Task 2", "Task 3". After reload there can be 2 or none). I thought this is because of JS famous sync/async behaviour.

So, how can I make the page render subjects in the same order and how to render excersises individualy for every subject?

Subject class

```
export class Subject
{
    constructor(id: string, name: string){
        this.Id = id
        this.name = name
    }
    Id: string
    name: string
}
```

Excersise class

```
import { Subject } from './Subject'

export class Excersise
{
    Id: string
    title: string
    content: string
    correctAnswer: string   
    subject: Subject 
}
```

SubjectExcersise class

```
import { Subject } from './Subject';
import { Excersise } from './Excersise';

export class SubjectExcersise{
    constructor(sub: Subject, ex: Excersise[]){
        this.subject = sub
        this.excersises = ex
    }
    subject: Subject
    excersises:Excersise[]
}
```

This is how **subEx** looks after ***GetSubjects()***

```
0: SubjectExcersise
excersises:
   0: {id: "ea9bce1d-b6bf-471e-b1df-6edb253d68e7", title: "Task2", content: "string", correctAnswer: 
   "string", subject: {…}}
   1: {id: "89121437-d01d-461b-b0a1-92b2798bd66e", title: "Task1", content: "string", correctAnswer: 
   "string", subject: {…}}
   2: {id: "3643f5db-5271-4c70-abb8-cc4a2f00d1ae", title: "Task3", content: "string", correctAnswer: 
   "string", subject: {…}}
subject: {id: "d0d20a1e-8a75-4d56-0c67-08d892dcbbe6", name: "Матан"}

1: SubjectExcersise
   excersises: []
subject:{id: "b827616b-8ee3-4dee-0c69-08d892dcbbe6", name: "Эконометрика"}

2: SubjectExcersise
excersises:
   0: {id: "955a704a-00dc-4fe0-a953-5d8dd8ce4d35", title: "Task1", content: "string", correctAnswer: 
   "string", subject: {…}}
   1: {id: "fe0dd1a7-2ee1-4948-9145-864a0b07b506", title: "Task2", content: "string", correctAnswer: 
   "string", subject: {…}}
subject: {id: "aad23a48-f04e-4114-0c68-08d892dcbbe6", name: "РИС"}
```

Comment: Maybe you should unsubscribe the variables at ngOnDestroy

Answer (score 0):

You can actually use the RxJS operators to create an observable for `SubjectExcersise[]` and you can use that observable inside your template using `async` pipe. Something like below:

**Component Class:**

```
  subEx$: Observable<SubjectExercise[]> = new Observable([]);
  getSubjects() {
    this.subEx$ = this.subService
      .GetSubjectsByUserId(localStorage.getItem('id'))
      .pipe(
        // Here we are automatically unsubscribing from previous subscription and
        // subscribing to next subscription i.e., `this.exService.GetExcesisesBySubject`
        switchMap((subjects) =>
          // This will only emit once each of exercises has emitted non undefined value atleast once
          combineLatest(
            // Here we are iterating over each subject and fetching the exercises
            ...subjects.map((subject) =>
              this.exService
                .GetExcesisesBySubject(subject.map)
                // Here we are creating subject exercises
                // These `SubjectExercises` will be assigned to `this.subEx$` as an observable
                .pipe((res) => new SubjectExercise(subject, res))
            )
          )
        )
      );
  }
```

**Component Template**

```
      <div class="list-group list-group-flush">
          <button *ngFor="let sub of subEx$ | async" type="button" class="btn btn-success dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
            {{sub.subject.name}}
            <div class="dropdown-menu">
                <a *ngFor="let ex of sub.excersises" class="dropdown-item">{{ex.title}}</a>
            </div>
          </button>
      </div>
```

I hope it would help.

Comment: Could U show the code after .pipe as it shoul be, cause I'm realy lost in this callbacks after c# (((
And yeah, I'm new to TypeScript

Comment: Which `pipe`? First one or second?

Comment: Mmm.. all) Any way, I've found out that the second ngFor doesn't iterate at all. It goes only through exercises of the first subject. I've added index to the first **ngFor**
`<a *ngFor="let ex of subEx[i].excersises" class="dropdown-item">{{i+"-"+ex.title}}</a>`
and after render all dropdowns have 0 at the beginning. I've seen similar question, but there was a problem with naming...

Comment: So do you have some confusion or is it resolved?

Comment: Still nothing. I've tryed the same thing with 2d array `( test:number[][] = [[1,2],[4,5,6],[7,8,9,10]];)` and also tried *ngFor with `<ul>` and `<li>` tags. This is what happened
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ChsWlmGevEbigR5sOLIptzBdPTS1OMv5/view?usp=sharing 
it doesn't iterate in case of `<button>`, but iterates with `<li>`
I'm confused...

Comment: Can you please share it using stackblitz?

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-q8yl97?file=src/app/app.component.html
And it works fine there... I couldn't make dropdown work properly, but when I look in devtools it shows correct indexes and data. And on py machine it works fine when I remove  `dropdown-menu` class